# Invertir cadenas obtenidas

Tags: c#, visual-studio, string, lista

Hola amigos buenas noches espero me puedan ayudar por favor, 
tengo el siguiente ejercicio ingresar una cadena ejemplo:abc123defg4567
y el resultado debe ser: cbagfed28
mi problema es que separo letras y números los números 
los sumo pero las cadenas de texto no logro separarlas, invertirlas y que queden
en la misma posición como el resultado que se espera.
lo mas cercano que obtengo con mi código es el siguiente: gfedcba28 
de antemano muchas gracias!

```
string acomulador = "";
string cadena = textBox1.Text;
string numeros = "";
string letra = "";
int palabra1 = 0;
int aux = 0;
List<string> caracter = new List<string>();
String cadenainvertida = "";
foreach (var letrados in cadena){
    cadenainvertida = letrados + cadenainvertida;
}
for (int i = 0; i < cadenainvertida.Length; i++){
    letra = cadenainvertida.Substring(i, 1);
    if (letra == "1" || letra == "2" || letra == "3" || letra == "4" || letra == "5" ||
        letra == "6" || letra == "7" || letra == "8" || letra == "9" || letra == "0"){
            numeros += letra;
            palabra1 = Convert.ToInt32(letra);
        }
        else{
            if (numeros != ""){
                caracter.Add(numeros);
                numeros = "";
            }
                MessageBox.Show(acomulador += letra);
            }
            }
            if (numeros.Length > 0)
                caracter.Add(numeros);
            foreach (var palabras in caracter)
            {
                int num = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < palabras.Length; i++)
                {
                    num += Convert.ToInt32(palabras.Substring(i, 1));
                }
                aux = aux += num;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(acomulador += " " + aux);
```

Answer (score 0):

Con Foreach recorres el texto completo, Si se puede parsear el numero, `Int.TryParse` te devuelve un true o false y parsea el numero de ser true y lo va sumando, sino es numero con `else` te concatena la cadena.

```
        string texto = "abc123defg4567";

        int valor = 0;
        int total = 0;
        string concatenar = string.Empty;
        string cadenainvertida = string.Empty;

        foreach (var item in texto)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out valor))
            {
                total = valor + total;
            }
            else
            {
                concatenar += item.ToString();
            }
        }
//En el for, recorremos tu cadena limpia de numeros pero de forma invertida.
//y la concateno al reves, luego de ese proceso le volvemos a concatenar la suma.
        for (int i = concatenar.Length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            cadenainvertida += concatenar[i - 1].ToString();
        }
        cadenainvertida = cadenainvertida + total;
```

Answer (score 0):

El planteamiento es ir sumando los dígitos que aparecen y conformar las cadenas, de forma que cuando encuentro un dígito opero sobre la cadena que hubiera podido formar y la invierto.

El código sería así:

```
    string texto = "abc123defg4567";

    int valor = 0;
    int total = 0;
    string textoParcial = "";
    string Resultado = "";

    foreach (var item in texto)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out valor))
        {
            total = valor + total;
            // Como ya hemos encontrado un dígito, pues lo que lleváramos
            // en textoParcial lo invertimos y añadimos al Resultado
            Resultado += ReverseText(textoParcial);

            // Ahora vaciamos el textoParcial para formar otra subcadena
            textoParcial = "";
        }
        else
        {
            textoParcial += item.ToString();
        }
    }
    // Para finalizar conformamos el Resultado final
    Resultado = Resultado + ReverseText(textoParcial) + total;
```

Para invertir el texto se crea una función para ello de la siguiente forma:

```
    string ReverseText(string input)
    {
        char[] array = input.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(array);
        return new String(array);
    }
```